# Two circles intersect orthogonally

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Suppose I have two circles in the complex plane $|z - a| = r$ and $|z - b| = s$ (with $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$), are there any ways I can test to see if these two circles intersect orthogonally without working in $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ coordinates?

Comment: Sure. If they intersect orthogonally, say $c$ is one intersection, then the triangle with vertices $a,b,c$ is right-angled. So $r^2+s^2 = \lvert a-b\rvert^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If they intersect orthogonally, the triangle with corners at $a$, $b$ and an intersection point will be a right triangle. Use Pythagoras on that triangle:
$$r^2+s^2=|a-b|^2.$$